# scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError when building a project against Scala 2.10 RC1

Tags: scala, build, gradle, scala-2.10

I am attempting to build our old projects against Scala 2.10.0 RC1. Here's the error I get when I do it:

```
rahul@acb70333:~/Projects/Vayana/gryphon-camel-scala> gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala
[ant:scalac] scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.beans.BeanInfo in compiler mirror not found.
[ant:scalac]    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
...
[ant:scalac]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileScala'.
> Compile failed because of an internal compiler error (object scala.beans.BeanInfo in compiler mirror not found.); see the error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 24.7 secs
```

Full stack trace here: https://www.refheap.com/paste/6228.

What does this error message mean? Am I missing some libraries on classpath?

Comment: You must have `scala-reflect.jar` on classpath, if you're using reflection

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, we are using gradle and here is the relevant section from the build file of the project - https://www.refheap.com/paste/6277. We are not using reflection anywhere in our code.

Comment: Try mailing list. Oh, and, BTW, AFAIK, ScalaTools migrated to Maven Central.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, posted two days ago - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scala-user/nJSlzlcawFs. :(

Comment: @NikitaVolkov, yes, I am aware of the migration. We have our build files updated accordingly. Pretty sure the jar availability isn't an issue. Or else gradle would've outputted a different error.

Comment: After all it could very well be a bug of Scala. From my experience everything related to reflection is still a bit fragile. BTW, have you considered giving [scala-maven-plugin](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin) a try or migrating the project from Gradle to Maven? I'm suggesting that because I am using the RC1 with reflection in Maven with no problems.

Comment: I am afraid that won't be possible. We have invested a lot in Gradle. Writing custom plugins and all that. But thank you for your suggestion! It is appreciated.